# How to extend and redefine a clojure macro?

Tags: clojure, macros

I want to extend and redefine a clojure.core macro. For example, how can I redefine `clojure.core/defn` while using the original definition?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit tricky, but by aliasing the macro in `clojure.core` this is possible.

Open the repl and follow the steps below.

```
➜  ~ clj
Clojure 1.9.0
```

First alias `clojure.core/defn` to something else:

```
user=> (in-ns 'clojure.core)
#object[clojure.lang.Namespace 0x48e92c5c "clojure.core"]
clojure.core=> (defmacro defn-holder [])
#'clojure.core/defn-holder
clojure.core=>  (alter-var-root #'defn-holder (constantly (var-get #'defn)))
#object[clojure.core$defn__5154 0xd3957fe "clojure.core$defn__5154@d3957fe"]
```

Next, create a new defn macro that uses the alias definition

```
clojure.core=> (in-ns 'user)
#object[clojure.lang.Namespace 0x64ba3208 "user"]
user=> (defmacro defn [& args] `(do (println "aliased version")(clojure.core/defn-holder ~@args)))
WARNING: defn already refers to: #'clojure.core/defn in namespace: user, being replaced by: #'user/defn
#'user/defn
user=> (defn foo [a])
aliased version
#'user/foo
user=> (foo 1)
nil
```

However it doesn't work for all namespaces yet:

```
user=> (ns bar)
nil
bar=> (defn foo [a])
#'bar/foo
```

We need to redefine defn in clojure.core with our new definition:

```
bar=> (in-ns 'clojure.core)
#object[clojure.lang.Namespace 0x48e92c5c "clojure.core"]
clojure.core=> (alter-var-root #'defn (constantly (var-get #'user/defn)))
#object[user$defn 0x37052337 "user$defn@37052337"]
```

Now it works:

```
clojure.core=> (in-ns 'bar)
#object[clojure.lang.Namespace 0x37efd131 "bar"]
bar=> (defn foo [a])
aliased version
#'bar/foo
```

Comment: This is an interesting exercise in showing off the flexibility of the language, but please don't actually do this. Ever.

Comment: I have my reasons, but yeah you are right, one should in general not do this :)